# C# Serializing an objects into JSON but retain the name

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

So I'm trying to serialize a `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>
```

My class contains a property called `MyPropery`

However the string comes out as `"{"List1":[{"MyProperty":[]}]}"`

How would I be able to make it convert to `{"List1":["MyClass":{"MyProperty":[]}]}`

Comment: If you need that format, I would suggest you to add a class, within it add a string property and Myclass object.

Comment: `["name":"value"]` is invalid JSON. You can't have property names in an array `[]`, just in an object `{}`.

Comment: The `JSON` what you want as `output` is itself an invalid `JSON`

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you would need something like:

```
var obj = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, MyClass>>>();
```

As [kalimag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10674402/kalimag) pointed out, `["attr": "value"]` isn't a valid JSON. The serialization of the object `obj`, illustrated above, could yield something like:

```
{"List1": [{"MyClass": {"MyProperty": []}}]}
```

Which is a valid JSON.